# Jquery clone form values and replace form field id

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, clone

I am trying to clone a row to keep the values in my text box and comments field and doing a regex expression to do a partial replace of the id from crs1 to crs2.  However, I am not able to get this to work.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="info-crs1">Course Information


       <div id="course-crs1">
        <label for="txtcourse-crs1">Course 1</label><input type="text" id="txtcourse-crs1"/>
       </div> 
       <div id="grade-crs1">
         <label for="txtgrade-crs1">Grade 1</label><input type="text" id="txtgrade-crs1"/>
        </div>
        <div id="comments-crs1">Comments 1
           <textarea id="ta-comments-crs1"></textarea>
        <div>    
   </div>
</div>    
<input type="submit" value="clone">
```

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/nLk6wg0o/5/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need IDs?

Comment: @A.Wolff I need the ids because when the user submits the form, the formmail programs needs them to identify the values that have been submitted by each form control (text box, text area etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code replaces your original element with the replaced one. To fix this you can replace the last two lines with this:

```
$original.after(newhtml);
```

To clone the values your first have to fixate them with something like this. This code should be run before you clone:

```
// Fixate
$('#info-crs1 input').each(function(i, el) {
   $(el).attr('value', $(el).val()); 
});
```

Note that this will only work for input fields and not for your textarea. To get the textarea working you'll need to add some extra code in the fixate loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/nLk6wg0o/6/